# Objective-C removing objects from NSArray containing indexpath

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've an array which contains NSIndexPath and I want to remove all objects which have the same IndexPath.Row. My current code has some issues, not all the objects with same Row are removed.
My code is:

```
 rowValue=(int)btn.tag;
 for (int i=0; i<[SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems.count; i++)
{
    NSIndexPath * Path = [[SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems objectAtIndex:i];
    int section = (int) Path.section;
    if (section == rowValue)
    {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems objectAtIndex:i];
        [[SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems removeObjectAtIndex:i];

    }
}
```

Comment: You are iterating and at the same time modifying your array (especially removing items).

Comment: Yeah I know. What should I do?

Comment: you can use for each, then delete the object [[SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems removeObject: indexPath];

Comment: May I know why you are comparing Row with Section ?

Comment: its not a Row actually. Its a section only. I am getting a RowValue from button tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove objects like this

```
rowValue=(int)btn.tag;
NSMutableArray *arrTemp = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i=0; i<[SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems.count; i++)
{
    NSIndexPath * Path = [[SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems objectAtIndex:i];
    int section = (int) Path.section;
    if (section == rowValue)
    {
        [arrTemp addObject:[[SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
[[SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems removeObjectsInArray:arrTemp];
```

Comment: You saved me :D

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
rowValue=(int)btn.tag;

int countItem = [SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems.count;

for (int i=0; i < countItem ; i++)

{

 NSIndexPath * Path = [[SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems objectAtIndex:i];

    int section = (int) Path.section;

    if (section == rowValue)
    {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems objectAtIndex:i];
            [[SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems removeObjectAtIndex:i];

    }
}
```

store your count in different variable and run loop on that because when you remove your item from indexpath it changes your totalcount.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the indices of the items to be deleted in an indexset and remove the items by index. 
This is what I do.

```
 rowValue=(int)btn.tag;
        NSMutableIndexSet *indicesToRemove = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<[SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems.count; i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath * Path = [[SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems objectAtIndex:i];
        int section = (int) Path.section;
        if (section == rowValue)
        {
        [indicesToRemove addIndex:i]
        }
    }
    [[SingletonClass singleton].arraySubMenuItems removeObjectsAtIndexes:indices];
```